# ANDROID: Not able to add the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" to manifest file

Tags: java, android

I want to get rid of the Activity Title Bar and have tried just adding

`@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` to activity and

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to the manifest file.

But I keep getting the error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Nothing seems to help.

Any help would be wonderful :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

> Note: If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar,
>   then you must use (or override) the Theme.AppCompat family of styles
>   (rather than the Theme.Holo family, available in API level 11 and
>   higher). In doing so, each style property that you declare must be
>   declared twice: once using the platform's style properties (the
>   android: properties) and once using the style properties included in
>   the Support Library (the appcompat.R.attr properties—the context for
>   these properties is actually your app). See the examples below for
>   details.